# Blazor WASM Prerender Login Page - While waiting for the webassembly to load?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've been working with blazor wasm for several months but I'm dealing now with the need to reduce the initial load of the application.

The application should present a welcome screen with a classic login dialog.  I already prerendered the page , but what I want to achieve is that if the user enters his data and presses "LOGIN" the application will :

1. if the WASM finished loading, just login now with the WASM fully loaded
2. if it's still loading, present a loading until it finishes.

Do you think it's possible? I'm using an authentication provider of course for the login process.

Thank you!
Victor

Comment: You'd have to add an event using JavaScript that listens for when WASM is fully loaded. Perhaps utilize the `App.razor`'s `OnInitialized()` method to fire said event using `IJSRuntime`? Check this out: https://www.meziantou.net/showing-a-loading-screen-while-initializing-a-blazor-application.htm